# Pandas loads JSON file DatetimeIndex and not float

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following JSON file which I saved from a pandas dataframe:

```
{
  "A": {
    "69.0": 0,
    "69.5": 0,
    "70.0": 0,
    "70.5": 0,
    "71.0": 0
  },
  "B": {
    "69.0": 1,
    "69.5": 2,
    "70.0": 3,
    "70.5": 4,
    "71.0": 5
  },
  "C": {
    "69.0": 1,
    "69.5": 1,
    "70.0": 1,
    "70.5": 1,
    "71.0": 1
  }
}
```

When I run

```
df = pd.read_json("df.json")
```

I get the dataframe but the index is a DatetimeIndex
and `df.tail()` returns:

```
A  B  C
1970-01-01 00:01:09.000  0  1  1
1970-01-01 00:01:09.500  0  2  1
1970-01-01 00:01:10.000  0  3  1
1970-01-01 00:01:10.500  0  4  1
1970-01-01 00:01:11.000  0  5  1
```

I want the index to be a float and not a `DatetimeIndex`.
How can I load the JSON with the correct index type?
I cannot change the original JSON.

Thanks

Comment: How about letting pandas know about your [table schema](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following **dictionary**:

```
In [101]: d
Out[101]:
{'A': {'69.0': 0, '69.5': 0, '70.0': 0, '70.5': 0, '71.0': 0},
 'B': {'69.0': 1, '69.5': 2, '70.0': 3, '70.5': 4, '71.0': 5},
 'C': {'69.0': 1, '69.5': 1, '70.0': 1, '70.5': 1, '71.0': 1}}
```

you can construct a DF as follows:

```
In [102]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[102]:
      A  B  C
69.0  0  1  1
69.5  0  2  1
70.0  0  3  1
70.5  0  4  1
71.0  0  5  1
```